# 'advance study' or 'advance studies'. Which one is suitable in this context of usage?

Tags: sentence

In this context of usage which one is suitable?

> sentence: "make the transition into advance studies/study a smooth one"

Comment: *Advance* studies would be studies taken *in advance of* (that is, *before*) some other activity. *Advanced* studies are studies beyond basic studies. *His advance study of Italian proved of great advantage when he arrived in Rome for advanced studies in the Risorgimento.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would normally use *advanced study* for the activity, and *advanced studies* for the matters studied.

As such, either would be correct, but *advanced studies* is the more idiomatic, so go with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please take a look at my letter of motivation for a masters programme?

Comment: @JasperLoy I know. I was just looking for a personal favor